# Gap locking mysql

Tags: mysql

I need a clarification on MySQL docs excerpt:

> ...conflicting locks can be held on a gap by different transactions.
>   For example, transaction A can hold a shared gap lock (gap S-lock) on 
>   a gap while transaction B holds an exclusive gap lock (gap X-lock) on
>   the same gap...
>
> Gap locks in InnoDB are “purely inhibitive”, which means they only
>   stop other transactions from inserting to the gap.  They do not
>   prevent different transactions from taking gap locks on the same gap.
>   Thus, a gap X-lock has the same effect as a gap S-lock.

I have a table "aaa" with two columns - number (PRIMARY INDEX) and "mark" - VARCHAR with no index. Now I execute:

```
 Window1    
     SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
     BEGIN;
     SELECT * FROM aaa WHERE mark < 6 FOR UPDATE;
 Window2
     SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
     BEGIN;
     SELECT * FROM aaa WHERE mark < 6 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

Statement in Window1 acquires an x-lock on the record "mark = 6" and the preceding gap.

Now statement in Window2 asks for an s-lock on the exact same record and gap, which (according to docs) should be granted immidiately - but it's not!

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please include a link to the page where you copied the excerpt from. Was it this? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks

Comment: Yes - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html?acf=1#add-comment .

Answer (score 0):

Do you have data with mark < 6? If so, X record locks would be granted by the 1st transaction, along with the gap lock. The 2nd transaction couldn't acquire S record lock on those record.